# Bootstrap отключить закрытие модального окна при нажатии на темный фон

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Добрый день. В Bootstrap при нажитаи на кнопку

```
<button id="bs-example-modal-lg-newOrder" class="btn btn-info" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-newOrder">Новый</button>
```

Появляется стандартное модальное окно.

почитать можно тут:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Как решить задачу, чтобы модальное окно не закрывалось при нажатии на темный фон, а только при нажатии на кнопку закрыть?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').modal({
      backdrop: 'static',
      keyboard: false
    })
</script>
```

Или

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
```

Пример:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**Update by @Other:**
Свойство `backdrop` управляет фоном:
`true` - затемнение, закрывает окно по клику на фон.
`false` - без затемнения, фона нет -> кликать некуда.
`static` - фон есть, клик по фону не закрывает окно. <-- Это Вам нужно.